# scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.ev Error: shape mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

```
template = It[rect[0]:rect[2]+1,rect[1]:rect[3]+1]
    #warp is updated using p and It1 is warped
    warp = rect     #check if rect is passed as reference
    np.add(warp,np.array((p[0],p[1],p[0],p[1])),out=warp, casting="unsafe")

    X = np.arange(warp[0],warp[2]+1)
    Y = np.arange(warp[1],warp[3]+1)

    im_spline = RectBivariateSpline(X,Y,It1[warp[0]:warp[2]+1,warp[1]:warp[3]+1])
    im_warped = im_spline.ev(X,Y)
```

I am trying to interpolate a rectangle over an image when the rectangle moves a fractional distance. I used RectBivariateSpline from scipy but evaluation throws the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I am confused since X and Y don't necessarily have to be of the same shape